# Yaml behavior - parsing with python

Tags: python

I am unable to understand a peculiar behaviour of yaml parsing using python. 
My Yaml file

```
    - mappings:
       xyz:
         family: app
         image: mine-2-455-1
         containerName: image-1
         containerPort: 9020
         appenv: dev
         label: cds-containers
         count: 2
```

Code

```
  config = open(confFile)
  confParser =  yaml.load(config)
  taskFamily = str(confParser[2]['mappings']['xyz']['family'])
  print taskFamily
  imageName =  str(confParser[2]['mappings']['xyz']['image'])
  print imageName
  containerName = str(confParser[2]['mappings']['xyz']['containerName']),
  print containerName
```

The yaml is quite big with similar values. The problem comes in the output,

```
 xyz
 mine-2-455-1
 ('image-1',)
```

Somehow, it considers my 'containerName' value to be a tuple and I am unable to pass this to ecs boto since it expects strings and not tuples. Wondering why this happens and how to rectify.

I switched from safeload to load for yaml but that does not seem to have any effect. Any inputs please.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The comma on this line is causing it to be treated as a tuple:

```
containerName = str(confParser[2]['mappings']['xyz']['containerName']),
```

The fix is to remove the trailing comma.

Comment: bang! on target.. this was totally unexpected. Thanks a ton